# failed attments to post data to input box in php curl

Tags: php, php-curl

hi everyone so i have an idea to automate the attendance in my uni the website they use uses 2 data entery points the student id and csfmiddletoken but i cant seem to input the data using php curl i tried to different methods and both didnt work sadly

method 1

```
<?php

    $url = "http://x.com";
    $username = "111";

    $csrf_token_field_name = "csrfmiddlewaretoken";
    $params = array(
                    "student_id" => $username
                    );

    $token_cookie= realpath("test.txt");

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $token_cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $token_cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);


    if (curl_errno($ch)) die(curl_error($ch));
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($response);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
    $tokens = $dom->getElementsByTagName("input");
    for ($i = 0; $i < $tokens->length; $i++)
    {
        $meta = $tokens->item($i);
        if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'csrfmiddlewaretoken')
            $t = $meta->getAttribute('value');
    }
    if($t) {
        $csrf_token = file_get_contents(realpath("another-cookie.txt"));
        $postinfo = "";
        foreach($params as $param_key => $param_value)
        {
            $postinfo .= $param_key ."=". $param_value . "&";
        }
        $postinfo .= $csrf_token_field_name ."=". $t;

        $headers = array();

        $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
        $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
        $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
        $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
        $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
        $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
        $header[] = "Pragma: ";
        $headers[] = "X-CSRF-Token: $t";
        $headers[] = "Cookie: $token_cookie";

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $token_cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $token_cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 260);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

        ob_start();
        $html = curl_exec($ch);
        $result = curl_getinfo($ch);
        ob_get_clean();

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($result);
        echo "</pre>";
        print($html);

        if (curl_errno($ch)) print curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }

?>
```

method 2

```
<?php

    include "simple_html_dom.php";

$ch = curl_init("http://x.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($response);
$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('input');
for($i = 0; $i < $tags->length; $i++){
    $grab = $tags->item($i);
    if($grab->getAttribute('name') === 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'){
        $token = $grab->getAttribute('value');
    }
}
echo $token;
$data = array(
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken"=> $token,
    "student_id"=> '123'

);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://x.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;

?>
```

so basically usually the link would just show a input box to input ur id and then it would register ur attendance all i want is to be able curt post the data to the input box

Comment: x.com is NOT the website you're trying to access, we either need the full HTML and headers of the website, or the actual website itself, to help you. You're providing neither, so we cannot help you. I voted to close this question as `needs debugging details` - specifically we need the website, or the headers+html responses the website is giving.

Comment: btw you should check out DOMXPath: ```$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($response);$xp = new DOMXPath($dom); $token = $xp->query("//input[@name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']")->item(0)->getAttribute("value");```